# Query was empty. В чем ошибка?

Tags: sql

НЕ могу, внимательность сегодня спит. помогите

```
$username="root";
$passwd="";
$hostname="localhost";
$basename="azbuka";
$db_conect=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$passwd) or die ("Ошибка, нет доступа к базе");
mysql_select_db($basename,$db_conect);
$SQL="SELECT id_web,name,address,city FROM markets where y_precision is NULL";
$TData=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SQL и mysql_query($sql)
```

В PHP имена переменных регистрозависимы, то есть $SQL и $sql - две записи в списке переменных скрипта.

Comment: точно. ну спасибо, а то совсем торможу